# How to test promise in jasmine & karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, tdd, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a test case as follow:

```
it("Should have a valid structure", function(done){ 

    var data;
    module(APP_MODULE_NAME);

    inject(function(_metaService_){
        metaService = _metaService_;            
    });

    metaService.fetchEntityMeta('person').then(function(data){
        expect(data.status).toBe( true );
        done();
    });

});
```

But i am getting following error:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I have increased jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL but not use. 
But following code does work.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        done();
    }, 5000);
```

So, my understanding is I am having problem with promise. 
My question is how can i check the data returned by the promise.

Comment: provide your service code..

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `done()` callback anywhere in your test. Change the last statement to

```
metaService.fetchEntityMeta('person').then(function(data) {
    expect(data.status).toBe(true);
    done();
});
```

Another option is

```
metaService.fetchEntityMeta('person').then(function(data) {
    expect(data.status).toBe(true);
}).then(done);
```

Comment: my bad, now i am getting: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. And changing jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL is not helping.

Comment: Does your assertion pass? i.e. does `data.status` actually equal `true`?

Comment: Also, which of the above methods does not work for you? Or both?

Comment: Both of the above method are giving same error. & data.status is true. It is being sent from a mock response. Another thing to notice is that the execution is not accessing the then() block at all.